# SMART on FHIR client-js: Invalid Character Error on IE11

Tags: javascript, oauth-2.0, hl7-fhir, dstu2-fhir, smart-on-fhir

*Note:* The issue is also reported on [GitHub](https://github.com/smart-on-fhir/client-js/issues/55). Please take a look at Git issue as well for current progress/investigation.

I'm using [fhir-client v0.1.15](https://github.com/smart-on-fhir/client-js/releases/tag/v0.1.15) to develop a SMART on FHIR web application that would run in EHR launch scenario. For example in Epic Hyperspace simulator that uses IE to run the SMART application.

While testing my application locally(localhost) on IE11, I get a JavaScript error from within fhir-client.js.

> [SCRIPT1014](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/scripting/javascript/misc/invalid-character-javascript): Invalid character
>
> File: fhir-client.js, Line: 38113, Column: 3

Below are the two lines from code. 38112 & 38113 in order:

```
  var ret = Adapter.get().defer();
  var state = JSON.parse(sessionStorage[params.state]);
```

Any solution or workaround would be much appreciated.

**Updated**
Upon further investigation we found that sessionStorage is empty when line with JSON.parse executes. However, strange thing is why/how sessionStorage gets empty after redirection from authorization server. This only happens with IE11, everything works fine on Chrome though.

PS. Can someone please add a new tag [SMART](https://www.redoxengine.com/blog/what-is-smart-on-fhir/) or SMARTonFHIR?

Comment: Is there any value in params.state??

Comment: Yes there is. I debugged the code and it shows sessionStorage.length: 0 as opposed to 1 that is set in Chrome.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Though I couldn't find the exact root cause and solution but let me share the findings that helped me resolve this issue somehow.

The issue doesn't exist when I test my SMART application with redirect_uri(in FHIR.oauth2.authorize call) set to a staging server URL instead of localhost.

PS. I’m open to better, and more qualified answers for acceptance.